# how to execute docker diff command using kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am using docker diff in my application in order to find all changed files in a container. Now, my application manages containers through Kubernetes and don't have a direct access to them. I found Kubernetes implementations for several docker commands (like kubectl logs), bit docker diff is missed.

Is there a way to execute docker diff for a pod  through Kubernetes?

Many thanks

Answer (score -2):

Kubernetes (kubectl) does not offer an equivalent command. Ideally you should not be using this command at all outside your local development environment (which is docker)

The best practice is to start containers with readonly root filesystem, so that you avoid storing any important state in containers. Kubernetes can kill and restart your pod in another node as a new container, so you should not care about the `docker diff` that happens on the container.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My application just need to monitor all file system changes so there is no problem to restart a pod in another node as a new container. I agree with you, using readonly root filesystem is a good practice, unfortunately most of existing servers writes something to filesystem even if application logic doesn't

Comment: @ZavolokinRoman Did you find any solution for this?